# Javascript Proxy: what is the difference between these two cases?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I thought I kind of understood the behaviour of JS Proxy objects, but I am encountering some weird effects.

I define a simple handler that overrides get() by checking the following:

1. Check whether an object property is private (here, defined as "starts with an underscore") => return the value 'private'
2. Check whether an object property is defined => if not, return value 42 instead of whatever the value is.

This is how I define the handler:

```
var handler = {
  get: function(target, property){
    if (property.indexOf('_') === 0) {
      return 'private';
    }
    else {
      return property in target ? target[property] : 42;
    }
  }
};
```

Then, I use the handler in two different cases.

First, I use the proxy as it is to define an object **parent**, this works ok:

```
const parent = new Proxy({}, handler); 
parent._a = 10; 
parent.b = 20; 
console.log(parent._a, parent.b); // outputs: private, 20  -- OK! 
console.log('c' in parent, parent.c); // outputs: false, 42 -- OK!
```

Secondly, I created an object **p** derived from **parent**, and here is some odd behaviour that I don't understand:

```
const p = Object.create(parent);
p._a = 1;
p.b = 2;
console.log(p._a, p.b); // outputs: 1, 2 <--- why is this not caught by the proxy?
console.log('c' in p, p.c);// outputs: false, 42 <--- why is this caught by the proxy?
```

I would understand if no getter applied to p was trapped through the proxy, but why is the **p.c** call trapped, while the **p._a** is not?

Comment: you are trapping the prototype properties, not the own properties.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks! That would explain the difference between p._a / p.b and p.c. So just to see that I understand correctly: p.c is trapped because c is not found on p, so it is searched on the prototype, which is the proxy, where it is trapped. Right?

Comment: yes, that's exactly right; the prototype is a fallback to missing own properties

Comment: @dandavis: Thanks a lot! I knew all this stuff (in theory :D), but sometimes you end up not seeing the forest anymore for the trees.